# Why does load/require in irb not load local variables?

Tags: ruby

Why is it that when I require/load the below file in irb, `john` is an undefined variable but `Person` exists? Does require/load just run the file in the irb session so shouldn't I then have access to both `Person` and `john`?

**somefile.rb**

```
class Person
end

john = Person.new
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

require/load is not the same as just copying and pasting the file into irb. You do run the file but files have their own scope in ruby. The local variable you create `john` is scoped to that file. That means when you define it it is available in the file but not outside it. This is a good feature to have: imagine you have a different file that creates a `Dog` class and assigns `john = Dog.new`. When you loaded that file it would change the assignment of `john` in your first file, breaking any code that depends on `john` being a person. Many Ruby programs contain hundreds of files -- you can imagine how this would be painful. It's the same thing when you have two methods

```
def method1
  john = Dog.new
end

def method2
  john = Person.new
  method1()
  puts john
end
```

We want to be able to define variables and do things with them without worrying the other code we call will change them. If you call method2 you'll see that `john` is still a `Person`. If calling other methods could change your local variables it would be very hard to reason about what was happening.

Local variables inside files are scoped only to those files just like local variables inside methods are scoped only to those methods. If you want to access them outside the file, just make them constants.

```
JOHN = Person.new
```

Comment: thanks! but how come `class` isn't scoped to the file?

Comment: `class` is a keyword which *must* be given a constant. If you try `class person; end` you'll get a syntax error. In ruby constants are identifiers that start with a capital letter. `person` is a variable `Person` is a constant. Constants have different lexical scope from local variables: they can be accessed from the module they're defined in down through any submodules. If they're defined outside any module as in your example they are globally available.